# Change sender name doesn't work

Tags: c#, email, smtpclient, mailaddress

First of all, I search for an hour how to solve my problem on other posts but the other solutions don't work in my case.

**My problem**

I need to send a report mail after the execution of my program. To send mails I use `System.Net.Mail` namespace and particularly `SmtpClient` class.

The mail is correctly sent but I need to hide the sender mail address.

I tried some different things but none of them seems to work.

**What I tried**

Firstly I tried to do this :

```
public static void sendMail(String Titre,String Message)
        {
            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(GestionParametres.getParametre("SMTP"), Int32.Parse(GestionParametres.getParametre("PortSmtp")));
            client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(GestionParametres.getParametre("UsernameSmtp"), GestionParametres.getParametre("PasswordSmtp"));
            MailAddress from = new MailAddress(GestionParametres.getParametre("ExpediteurMail"),"Rapport interface ****");
            MailAddress to = new MailAddress(GestionParametres.getParametre("DestinataireMail"));
            MailMessage message = new MailMessage(GestionParametres.getParametre("ExpediteurMail"), GestionParametres.getParametre("DestinataireMail"));
            message.From = from;
            message.Subject = Titre;
            message.Body = Message;
            message.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
            client.Send(message);
        }
```

But the sender mail address still appear in mail.

Secondly, I tried this :

```
public static void sendMail(String Titre,String Message)
{
    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(GestionParametres.getParametre("SMTP"), Int32.Parse(GestionParametres.getParametre("PortSmtp")));
    client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(GestionParametres.getParametre("UsernameSmtp"), GestionParametres.getParametre("PasswordSmtp"));
    MailAddress from = new MailAddress(GestionParametres.getParametre("ExpediteurMail"));
    MailAddress to = new MailAddress(GestionParametres.getParametre("DestinataireMail"));
    MailMessage message = new MailMessage("Rapport interface ****" + GestionParametres.getParametre("ExpediteurMail"), GestionParametres.getParametre("DestinataireMail"), Titre, Message);
    client.Send(message);
}
```

But it doesn't work either...

Now I have no idea how to solve this problem.

Any idea ?

Thank you in advance,

Thomas

Comment: You create "to" and "from" variables, but you don't seem to use them?

Comment: @HansKesting I created them for my first test but I forgot to remove them in my second test. And in my first test, the `To` propertie is only readable

Comment: I have never got any mail without From header. Not even from spammers